# display system ringtones list in wp7 in a third party application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a wp7 application that requires me to tap on a textblock and on that tap the list of system ringtones should get displayed from which the user can select a ringtone. But unfortunately I am not able to find a way to do this. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible at this point of time, as the Microsoft.Phone.RingToneLibrary supports only the adding of the RingTones.
May be in future if Microsoft provides any API, then its possible to access system ringtones.